# Is there a way to create domain-object-translations over extbase in TYPO3 9?

Tags: typo3, translation, extbase, typo3-9.x

I'm importing some products with JSON into my TYPO3 extension.

I'm having problems with translation creating over my ImportService, as I upgraded from TYPO3 8 to TYPO3 9. It seems, that the l10n_parent in the database cannot be set, although _localizedUid and _versionedUid are being set.

```php
/**
 * @param DomainObjectInterface $object
 * @param $targetLanguageUid
 * @return DomainObjectInterface|null
 */
public function translate($object, $targetLanguageUid)
{
    /** @var AbstractDomainObject $objectCopy */
    $objectCopy = new $this->objectType;
    $properties = ObjectAccess::getGettableProperties($object);
    foreach ($properties as $propertyName => $propertyValue) {
        ObjectAccess::setProperty($objectCopy, $propertyName, $propertyValue);
    }
    $objectCopy->_setProperty('_localizedUid', $object->getUid());
    $objectCopy->_setProperty('_languageUid', $targetLanguageUid);
    $objectCopy->_setProperty('_versionedUid', $object->getUid());
    return $objectCopy;
}
```

Expected Result: l10n_parent in database is e.g. 403 (uid of original object)
Actual Result: l10n_parent in database is 0

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with TYPO3 internal data structures, the recommendation is to use the [DataHandler](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/ApiOverview/Typo3CoreEngine/Database/Index.html) for this. In your case, you just need to provide the config array and set the `localize` field correctly. You can use this in your own scripts with a backend scope, examples are provided in the [documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/ApiOverview/Typo3CoreEngine/UsingDataHandler/Index.html). In your import script, you would have to create the records in the default language first, then create each translation for it.